# Blank white screen after React run build

Tags: javascript, reactjs, npm

I created a react app which works when I run `npm start`, but when I run `npm run build`, It gives me a white screen. I tryed to fix it but to no avial. There are many similar questions, but none of those solutions fixed my problem. My code is below.

App.jsx:

```
import React from 'react';
import Home from './pages/Home/Home'
import SignIn from './pages/Sign-In/Sign-In'
import {
  BrowserRouter,
  Routes,
  Route,
} from "react-router-dom";


function App(){
    return(
    <BrowserRouter basename="/">
        <Routes>
            <Route path="/" element={<Home/>}/>
            <Route path="/sign-in" element={<SignIn/>}/>
        </Routes>
    </BrowserRouter>
    )
}

export default App;
```

package.json:

```
  "homepage": ".",
  "name": "frontend",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "type": "module",
  "private": true,
```

index.js:

```
import React from 'react';
import {createRoot} from 'react-dom/client';
import App from './App.jsx';


createRoot(document.getElementById('root')).render(<App />)
```

index.html(after build):

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <link rel="icon" href="./favicon.ico" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.1.1/css/all.min.css" integrity="sha512-KfkfwYDsLkIlwQp6LFnl8zNdLGxu9YAA1QvwINks4PhcElQSvqcyVLLD9aMhXd13uQjoXtEKNosOWaZqXgel0g==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer" />
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-ka7Sk0Gln4gmtz2MlQnikT1wXgYsOg+OMhuP+IlRH9sENBO0LRn5q+8nbTov4+1p" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <title>React Home</title>
    <script defer="defer" src="./static/js/main.3f6694dc.js"></script>
    <link href="./static/css/main.4026a363.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body>
    <div id="root"></div>
    <script src="../../../satishSite/frontend/src/index.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: this path `"../../../satishSite/frontend/src/index.js"` might be incorrect, do you have any error in the console ?

Comment: I have no errors in the console

Comment: can you be more explicit ?

Comment: I have completley nothing in the console. I think the path is correct, but I don't think that you would use the index.js file after you build your application

Answer (score 0):

I Think you opened "index.html" locally that's why it's showing a white screen.

don't open "index.html" locally, try to host your build folder to any server.
it's working on the server.

Comment: I tried serving it as a static file on my Flask-Python server, but still got the same result

Comment: you need to host your all code to any server

Comment: I put my code on a server loccally, still not working

Comment: can you share the white screen screenshot

Answer (score 0):

`script` in html should look like `<script src="/index.jsx" type="module">`, it does not need to go from root, and jsx files must always be declared as modules.

You should also use parcel to server your html files

`npm install parcel -D`

package.json:

```
scripts: {
  "dev":"parcel serve index.html"
}
```

Then run `npm run dev` in console

Comment: What do you mean? I exported the `export default App;`

Comment: My bad, did not see that line, what about the other two questions?

Comment: Do you mean this ```"scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },```

Comment: Yes, that's it, thanks.

Comment: Did you change the script source? If so, could you also link the `Home` function?

Comment: What do you mean by the script source? I changed the `../../../satishSite/frontend/src/index.js` to `/index.js`, but that didn't do anything

Comment: Yes, could you also link the `Home`function?

Comment: sure, here: ```import React from "react";
import ViewText from "./components/ViewText";
import Nav from "../Nav"
import "./home.css"


function Home(){
    return (
        <div>
            <Nav />
            <ViewText />
        </div>
    )
}

export default Home;```

Comment: Also, `index.js` should be `index.jsx`, and the `script src` should be `<script src="link" type="module">
Think that may solve it

Comment: I changed it to `<script src="link" type="module">`  but it is giving me a 404 in the console because `link` doesn't exist.

Comment: It should not say link, it should be the link to your script file, `/index.js` or what it is

Comment: It might also be `../index.js`, or `../server/index.js` depending on how you have set up the project